# Can not start nestjs project on the k8s server

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, nestjs

I am working on a nestjs project, this project can start by running, and works well :

```
npm run start:test
```

However, if I deploy the project to k8s, it will show :

[10:44:59 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[10:45:22 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

and never show that it is running.

here is my docker :

```
FROM node:16 AS builder

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV='prod'


# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.build.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY ca-cert.pem ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/
COPY protos ./protos/

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install
RUN npx prisma generate

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:16-alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist
COPY --from=builder /app/protos ./protos
COPY --from=builder /app/tsconfig.build.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/tsconfig.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/prisma ./prisma
COPY --from=builder /app/ca-cert.pem ./

EXPOSE 3190
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:test" ]
```

here is the package.json :

```
 "start:test": "nest start --watch",
    "start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": " nest start",
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

you should not `watch` the file in Kubernetes it just creates overhead, plus make sure there is proper `healthcheck` and `memory request`.

so better to change `cmd` to

```
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

but why we need to build the same package again? its pretty heavy process to build, so better to just consume `dist`

> nest start simply ensures the project has been built (same as nest build), then invokes the node command in a portable, easy way to execute the compiled application.
> NestJs already provides the correct command start:prod, but I (and Google) assumed the naked start was the call to invoke. Probably others make the same assumption. So do this instead:

```
{
    "start": "npm run start:prod",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
}
```

[How to get back to point 0 of memory consumption with NestJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72123632/how-to-get-back-to-point-0-of-memory-consumption-with-nestjs)

If you still want to work with the existing setup then make sure these

```
resources:
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 1000m
    memory: 2000Mi
```